# How can i direct my user to the page i want according to his type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I believe it's a simple logic, but as I'm still learning I'm having a bit of difficulty implementing it.

On the login page of my project, I get the data of who logged in after a post request. and in the user I have the field "type". There are 2 types of users only.

I want that, if the user has type A, he is redirected to the "home" page, if he is type B, he goes to the "main" page. If you don't have a type value defined yet, go to the "usertype" page.

I wrote this logic here but it's not working. can anybody help me?

heres my code

```
 async function onFinish(values) {
    let axiosConfig = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
    };

    Axios.post(
      `  /login`,
      {
        email: values.email,
        senha: values.password,
      },
      axiosConfig
    )
      .then((resp) => {
        var name = resp?.data[0]?.prinom;
        var userId = resp?.data[0]?.id; 
        var prodUser = resp?.data[0];
        localStorage.setItem("prodUser", JSON.stringify(prodUser)); 
        
        
        
        //here's the part i need help
        
        if (!resp?.data[0]?.tipo) history.push("/tipodeusuario");
        resp?.data[0]?.tipo === "pac" ? history.push("/homepac") : history.push("/home");
        
      })
```

Comment: have you tried window.location.href('yourpath') instead of history.push?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to store your response in a variable to have a readable code so :

`let apiResp = respoone.data.tipo;`

```
if (apiResp === A){
  history.push('/HomePage')
}if(apiResp === B) {
  history.push('/MainPAge')
}else {
  history.push('/userType')
}
```

You can also use "Switch Case" Approach.

Or Conditional (ternary) operator which I don't recommend because it makes your code less readable.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked and solved my problem...i'm very gratefull for your help

Answer (score 1):

After you find the user type (i.e., A or B)
you can simply assign a new url to `window.location`

Here's some pseudo code

```js
function getUserType(AorB){
  //Get user type
  return AorB;
}

//Store urls in a variable
let url = (getUserType('A') == 'A')? './UrlForUserTypeA':'./UrlForUserTypeB';

//Redirect
console.log('Redirecting...');
window.location = url;
```

Hope that's what you needed

Answer (score 1):

`useHistory` has changed in react-router v6. now we use `useNavigate`.

```
if (apiResp === A){
  navigate('/HomePage');
}if(apiResp === B) {
  navigate('/MainPage');
}else {
  navigate('/userType');
}
```

thanks @Amin Arshadinia :)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer here because I do not have enough reputation to comment.

Since you're using React.js, you can store the user type in a state and conditionally render a component that matches that state.

```js
  function MyApp() {
    const [userType, setUserType] = React.useState('')

    async function onFinish(values) {
      Axios.post().then((response) => {
        setUserType(reponse.data[0].tipo)
      })
    }

    return (
      <>
        {userType === 'A' 
         ? <RenderPageComponentA />
         : userType === 'B'
         ? <RenderPageComponentB />
         : <RenderPageComponentUserType />
        }
      </>
  )
  }
```

This lib might help you: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start